# Compare an array of strings to a string stored in a databse

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to compare a variable that contains a string of fruits and is stored in a mysql database to an array of fruits. My code looks like this:

```
$stored_fruits = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT fruits FROM fruit_table"); // uploaded fruits: "Apple Orange Pineapple"
$fruit_array = explode(", ", $fruits); // fruits are searched for and turned into an array: ["Apple", "Strawberry", "Banana"]
for($i = 0; $i < count($fruit_array); $i++) {
    if($fruit_array[$i] == substr($stored_fruits)) {
        echo "fruit match";
    }
}
```

`$fruits` is a string of fruits that is taken from what the user types in and `$stored_fruits` accesses strings of fruits already in the database. `$fruits` is an array that looks like `["Apple", "Pineapple", "Strawberry"]`. `$stored_fruits` looks like: `"Strawberry Orange Banana"`. I want to compare each element in the array to the uploaded fruits.  If there is a match, I want it to echo match.  Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `mysqli_query()` doesn't return the results of the query, you need to call `mysqli_fetch_assoc($stored_fruits)`. And you need to call it in a loop to get all the results.

Comment: There's no way that `$stored_fruits` can hold that string.

Comment: `substr()` needs at least 2 arguments: the string, a starting position, and an optional length. I think you really want to use `strpos()` to see if the string contains a substring.

Comment: Use `explode()` to turn the space-separated string into an array, then use `array_intersect()` to determine if the two arrays share any elements.

Comment: You seem to have very little understanding of any of the functions you're calling.

Comment: Does `fruit_table` really have just one row containing a space-separated list of fruits?

Comment: Not sure what you intended with `$this->,` in the first line.

Comment: The string is in one column, called "fruits", so I just used "SELECT fruits FROM fruit_table" because I thought that holds the value of the column.  I am not that experienced in PHP so there is a good chance I am wrong.  Thank you though.

Comment: @NigelRen `$this->connection` or something like that probably got lost in translation

Comment: fruit_table has two columns, one being an ID, the other being the string of fruits

Comment: $this->con is working and has been working for other parts in my project so I kept it the same

Comment: @evanb629 But you wrote `$this->` instead of `$this->con`.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad. Just some food for thought.

Comment: @Barmar i meant to write $this->con, where $con is my connection variable . . . my bad

Comment: So why don't you just fix it?

Comment: @Don'tPanic He's not storing a delimited list in the table. Each fruit is in a different row. He assumed that `mysqli_query()` would concatenate them.

Comment: @Barmar are you sure? Maybe I misinterpreted this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49520217/compare-an-array-of-strings-to-a-string-stored-in-a-databse#comment86046245_49520217

Comment: No, @Don't Panic is right.  I am storing the string of fruits in one row.  So one row could look like "Apple Banana Orange".

Comment: That's a bad design. And if you only have one row, why bother with an `ID` column?

Comment: I guess you're right.  I just thought that since each row in the table is different, it would make sense to put in an auto-incrementing ID along with the string of fruits.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the row containing the result of the query. Then you can use `explode()` to split the fruits using space as the delimiter, and compare the two arrays to see if they have any fruits in common.

```
$results = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT fruits FROM fruit_table");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
$stored_fruits = explode(" ", $row['fruits']);

$fruit_array = explode(", ", $fruits);
if (!empty(array_intersect($stored_fruits, $fruit_array))) {
    echo "fruit match";
}
```

But it would be better to have each fruit in a separate row of the table. Then you can fetch all the fruits with a loop:

```
$results = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT fruit FROM fruit_table");
$stored_fruits = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $stored_fruits[] = $row['fruit'];
}
```

Comment: `$fruits` is undefined

Comment: @Mike The question says that `$fruits` comes from user input. He just didn't show that code since it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: @Barmar I like the first idea better.  Also, instead of using explode() on the string, I will just store the list of strings as a pre-exploded array in the table, then I can use the array_intersect() function.

Comment: You can't store an array in a table.

Comment: Then I will store it as a comma and space seperated string then explode it like explode(", ", $fruits).

Comment: Like I said, that's a bad design. Did you read the linked question?

Comment: You're a beginner, this is a good time to avoid learning bad habits.